# examples sites that are large and run on Azure?

Tags: azure

I'm looking for examples that show Azure scales up well.  Does anyone know of any large, high-volume sites that run on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

This type of question seems out of scope. That said, try looking at some Windows Azure [case studies](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/case-studies/). This is where you're likely to find information on deployment details. Typically, deployment details aren't revealed to the general public, and those of us who *do* know about such deployments are usually bound by NDA's.